# Python задача в функциональном стиле: есть ли ноль среди данных N чисел

Tags: python, python-3.x

Проверьте, есть ли среди данных N чисел нули.

**Формат ввода**

Вводится число N, а затем N чисел.

**Формат вывода**

Выведите True, если среди введенных чисел есть хотя бы один нуль, или False в противном случае.

```
Тест 1
Входные данные:
3
4
19
14
Вывод программы:
False

Тест 2
Входные данные:
7
0
20
9
14
5
29
4
Вывод программы:
True
```

Не могу сделать чтение в функциональном стиле. 
Вот мой неработающий код:

```
print(any(map(i for i in range(a) if i == 0, input())))
```

Comment: Можно так: `foo = lambda value: True if 0 in [int(input()) for x in range(value)] else False` где `value`: кол-во чисел

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никогда не пишите подобного на реальных задачах. Лучше написать три понятных строчки, чем одну такую, в которой вы сами запутаетесь до того, как допишете её до конца.

Но если чисто ради прикола, то нужный вам код будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
print(0 in [int(input('Введите число:')) for _ in range(int(input('Введите количество чисел:')))])
```

Теперь кратко о том, что было не так в вашем коде:

1. "map" принимает первым аргументом функцию, вторым - итерируемый объект. У вас первым аргументом идёт итерируемый объект, вторым - функция.
2. Функция, которую вы указываете в "map" будет принимать аргументы из итератора. Что вы ожидаете получить, передавая в input() в качестве аргумента числа?
3. "any" возвращает True, если хотя бы одно число не ноль. Вам нужно наоборот выяснить - является ли хотя бы одно число нулём.
4. Если хотите использовать то, что ввёл пользователь, в качестве числа - то нужно обернуть это в int(). В идеале - ещё и обернуть это в исключение, но тут уже однострочник никак не получится.

Comment: Спасибо! Ваш разбор был очень полезен!

Comment: [] создаёт весь список целиком даже ели 0 может быть найден раньше. Можно на () заменить, чтобы закончить выполнение найдя ноль.

Answer (score 1):

```
not all(map(int, map(input, range(int(input())))))

any(s.strip() == '0' for s in map(input, range(int(input()))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Если предположить, что первая строка всегда не 0, т. е. подразумевается, что за N обязательно следует, какое-то множество, то можно написать так:

```
import sys
print(0 in map(int, sys.stdin.read().split('\n')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Печатаем `True` если есть `0` среди `n` заданных чисел (и `False` в противном случае):

```
import sys
from itertools import islice

print(any(x == 0 for x in map(int, islice(sys.stdin, int(next(sys.stdin))))))
```

1. `islice(it, n)` читает `n` элементов из `it` итератора (когда `any()` дёргает `for`-цикл, который в свою очередь дёргает `map()`, которая дёргает `islice`, которая дёргает `sys.stdin` -- без `any()` не было бы чтения). В данном случае, `islice()` читает заданное количество строк
2. `map(int,` превращает каждую прочитанную строку в целое число
3. `any(x == 0` выходит как только первый ноль встретится.

---

Вариант без импортов, используя только встроенные функции:

```
n = int(input())
print(n > sum(1 for _ in zip(range(n), iter(input, '0'))))
```

1. `n = int(input())` -- читаем количество чисел во вводе
2. `iter(input, '0')` -- читаем строки, пока `0` не встретится (целая строка `0`)
3. `zip(range(n),` гарантирует, что не больше `n` строк будет прочитано.

Оба варианта ленивые: читают ровно столько сколько нужно: как только `0` встречается, код завершает итерации. Код не читает более `(n + 1)` строк (раньше EOF может выйти даже если `0` не встретился).